# Where does "kubectl create secret generic NAME [--from-literal=key1=value1]" save it's result?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, jwt, kubectl, secret-key

I am just wondering to know what is the result of running the following command?

```
kubectl create secret generic NAME  [--from-literal=key1=value1]
```

Should we run it inside a specific file of the project?

Where does it save the result of running this command and how the application uses it's result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will create a secret with the data key, key1 and its respective value, value1 in whatever namespace is set in the `current-context` of your kubeconfig, (if you have not set this yourself it will be the `default` namespace).

> Should we run it inside a specific file of the project?

For this command, no, it does not matter. This is an *imperative* command, so in this instance it does not matter where you are on your machine when you run this command. Imperative commands provide all of the resources with your command, in this case a secret with the key key1 and its respective value. The command is not referencing any files in your project, so you can run this from anywhere.

You can contrast this to a similar resource creation command that provides the resource the declarative way:

```
kubectl apply -f my-file.yaml
```

this command says to take the resource in the file and create or update the resource - but I need to supply the path to the file, so it would matter in this instance.

> Where does it save the result of running this command

A request will be sent to the api-server which will try to create the object. Kubernetes will now include this object as part of its desired state, it will be stored in etcd. You can read more about the Kubernetes components in their docs - but insofar as it is relevant for this question, the secret object now exists in the cluster which is scoped to the current namespace the user is working in (see kubeconfig context).

Secrets are namespaced objects. This means if you want a pod to use the secret it will need to be in the same namespace as the secret. *If you have not explicitly set a namespace for your kubeconfig current-context*, your command will create a secret in the 'default' namespace. This also means that anyone with access to the default namespace also can access the secret.

to view your secret you can run
`kubectl get secret`
if you want to see your data in it
`kubectl get secret -o yaml`

> and how the application uses it's result?

There are a number of ways to consume secrets. Here is a example of how to set an env var from key1 in the secret data on a container for use.

note: this snippet only shows a section of a valid yaml template for a deployment which shows a container, named app, it's image and envs.

```yaml
...
  - name: app
    image: your-app
    env:
      - name: NAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: name
            key: key1
            optional: false # same as default; "name" must exist
                            # and include a key named "username"
...
```

(kubernetes secret docs) https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: Should I run this command only once and the created key will be stored permanently somewhere?

Comment: @GoodMan once you create the secret object it will be stored in the cluster's etcd.

Comment: This creates a persistent Secret resources in your Kubernetes cluster. It will exist until you explicitly delete it.

Comment: The command as written will not create a key in the "default" namespace. It will create a secret in whatever the current namespace is in the kubeconfig context.

Comment: @larsks absolutely! thankyou - edited.

Answer (score 1):

A [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) is a way of storing information in Kubernetes.

> Where does it save the result of running this command

When you run that `kubectl create secret` command, it will create a Secret resource in your current [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/). If you're unsure what namespace you're currently configured to use, you can view it by running:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts $(kubectl config current-context)  | awk '{print $NF}'
NAMESPACE
default
```

> How does the application uses it's result?

You can make the information in a secret available to an application in several ways:

- You can [expose Secret values as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)
- You can [mount Secrets as files on the filesystem](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)
- You can retrieve secrets via the Kubernetes API

The linked documentation contains examples that show what this looks like in practice.

Comment: Should I run this command only once and the created key will be stored permanently somewhere?  Where?

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=key1=supersecret --from-literal=key2=topsecret
```

Kubernetes creates the secret in the current active namespace, you can specify a different namespace without switching into it by just using `-n <namespace>`. Secrets, are stored in the internal etcd (which is not encrypted by default).

However, if you only want to see how the secret will look like, but not actually create the secret, simply add `--dry-run=client -o yaml` to the command:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=key1=supersecret --from-literal=key2=topsecret --dry-run=client -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  key1: c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=
  key2: dG9wc2VjcmV0
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-secret
```